# How to protect data from login form using angularjs in asp.net application?

Tags: asp.net, angularjs, forms, password-protection

i have a simple login form:

[image]

After click to submit button, data from form will send to server, but how i can protect this data ? I'm thinking what i can't send clear data without protect.
Thanks for your answers!

Comment: SO is a place where you get answers or help with particular technical issues ([help/dont-ask]). You should consider posting to Programmers on Stack Exchange. The answer to your question is perhaps SSL encrypted HTTP connection

Comment: Please be a lot more specific particularly in regards to what *"protect data"* even means. Agree that you probably want SSL and only submit on https protocol

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Fairly vague question you have here, but here's your basic security checklist for passwords.

- Submit sensitive details over POST only.
- Submit sensitive details over SSL only
- Store passwords securely (one-way hash function)

Answer (score 1):

Take a look at this [Javascript Crypto Library](https://github.com/bitwiseshiftleft/sjcl/tree/version-0.8).  It may help you.